# Density function, identify constant

Tags: probability

I got stucked with the following problem:

Identify the constant $c$ of the density function $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\frac{c*e^{-x}}{y^3}$ for the random variable $(X,Y)$, if $x\geq0$ and $y\geq1$, otherwise its $0$.

How could I solve this?

Thanks in advance,
greetings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to compute the integral $\displaystyle \int_0^\infty \int_1^\infty \frac{ce^{-x}}{y^3}\ dy\ dx$ and set the result equal to $1$.  Then you can solve for $c$.  (This works because the integral of a density function must be equal to $1$.)